# why does import torch for PyTorch stable(1.5) throws error on macOS

Tags: macos, import, pytorch, torch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/
```

copy libc++.1.dylib to the lib folder in Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/

this would resolve the issue